# Animation about a tribe living on a (tree root?) tether between two planets

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Looking for an animated show/movie. It's about a tribe that live on a tether between two planets, made up of something like tree roots.

The story is about one of them wanting to know more about the place they live and what is beyond their village.

Comment: These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Kaena: The Prophecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaena:_The_Prophecy) (2003).

> The film begins with an alien ship crash landing on a desert planet.
>   The alien survivors, known as Vecarians, are quickly killed by the
>   planet's predatory native inhabitants, the Selenites. **The ship's core,
>   Vecanoi, survives, and from it sprouts Axis, a massive tree reaching
>   up into space.**
>
> **600 years later, a race of human-like tree-dwellers have evolved
>   living in the branches of Axis.** One of them, a young girl named Kaena
>   (voiced by Kirsten Dunst), is an adventurous daydreamer who longs to
>   explore the world beyond the confines of her village. Kaena's
>   inquisitiveness is opposed as heresy by the village elder, who
>   commands his people to stay productive and toil for the villager's
>   gods (who are, unbeknownst to them, the Selenites living in the planet
>   below).

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Comment: @JenTibbits - [You're very welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)